# Why does colors keep changing when I use the push function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Please be kind enough to tell me why the colors keep changing when I use the push function in the following code and how to amend it so that the colors do not keep changing.

I have used a recursive function as well.

```
titlesArray = ["Subtitles", "Captions", "Chapters", "Description", "Interaction", "Metadata"];

function getTitles() { 
    var newArray = titlesArray.push("Subtitles", "Captions", "Chapters", "Description", "Interaction", "Metadata");
    var colors = ["Orange", "Yellow", "Blue", "Lime", "Purple", "Pink"];

    $('p').css('color', function(index) {
        return colors[index % colors.length];
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean they change?  `push` will mutate the array it acts upon.  Technically `newArray` is not a new array.  It will be the same array, with more elements added to it.

Comment: Actually `newArray` will most likely not be an array, but will be the length of the `titlesArray` after pushing more elements to it

Comment: There's no recursion shown in the code here... You've also tagged this [jsx] but there is no JSX code present. Please [edit] your question to include enough code to replicate the issue (a [mre]). You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>`) to reproduce the issue here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `newArray` from your `getTitles` function... It's not used at all and is just mutating your `titlesArray`.

If there's other parts of the function that needs the `newArray`, just use `var newArray = [].concat(titlesArray, titlesArray)` for a double length list of `titlesArray` without a mutation so your function doesn't have side effects..

To get the same result as what you have there currently that looks potentially unintended (due to the name of the variable): `var newArray = titlesArray.length * 2`

This seems to be all the bugs that exist based on the code that is currently visible.

Comment: The above concat function does not work since I'm putting the titles into a react grid. I have to use the push function for it to work. The bug is in the colors method. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can you add more of your code to let it be [a minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Otherwise, there's no real way for us to be sure we can actually help.

Comment: $('p').css('color', function(index) {
        return colors[index % colors.length];
    });

Comment: Okay, so, the main function of that looks fine, so the issue is likely that the number of `p` tags in your code is changing. Does mutating the `titlesArray` affect the number of p tags? If so, don't mutate the array. If not, we'll need a demo with the bug you are experiencing to be able to have a clue where the extra tags are coming from. Keep in mind that what we can see right now is a very limited section of code and it's hard to tell what might affect things without the full picture.